# Drag and drop with cypress in shadow dom

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cypress, shadow-dom, react-dnd

There is a problem in cypress with drag and drop in shadow dom.

I'm trying to run a drag event in such way:

> ```
> cy.get(".shadow-app>div>div:nth-child(1)", {
>   includeShadowDom: true
> }).trigger("dragstart", { dataTransfer2 });
> ```

And through `.shadow` function. No reaction.

I created an application with two similar lists.
https://github.com/mpetrikov/dnd-test

In the first list with real DOM, cypress works properly.
In the second list in a shadow DOM, cypress doesn't work. Even a dragstart event doesn't work.

In this file a test with these two attempts.
https://github.com/mpetrikov/dnd-test/blob/master/cypress/integration/dnd.js
I call a dragover two times because plugin 4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop does the same and it works. Just one dragover doesn't work.

---

This view after a dragstart in real DOM:

[image]

---

This view after the test (right list in shadow DOM):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the [plugin](https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop) caused by two issues:

1. Not using `composed: true` flag for drag events
2. Using `.closest('html')` returns null inside Shadow DOM.

Here is a patch which makes it work:
https://gist.github.com/web-padawan/a124e7cf90b5c252f0731c2d617ab6d7